# Some keys not working under screen in vim

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, vim, xterm

When using vim under screen, some keys are not working.

Namely, Pressing Alt-Left produces '3D'
and Alt-Right produces '3C'

Also, pressing Up/Down when scrolling list of files in Command-T plugin produces 'A' and 'B' respectively.

When I exit the screen and run vim just under ssh session, all works fine.

Are there any settings in screen itself or terminal server/client I can tweak to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your .screenrc section

```
term xterm
```

Or modify your .vimrc:

```
if match($TERM, "screen")!=-1
  set term=xterm
endif
```

For more information, see [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/GNU_Screen_integration)